# Javascript свойства обьектов

Tags: javascript, объекты

Комментариями помечена проблема

```
var obj = {a:2};
obj.b = 3;
var obj2 = {
  y: obj.b + obj.a,
  d: y //не могу свойству d присвоить значение свойства y
};
//obj2.d = obj2.y; //а вот так могу
console.log(obj2.y);
console.log(obj2.d);
```

Не могу свойству `d` объекта `obj2` присвоить значение свойства `y` этого же объекта.

Comment: так в чем вопрос?

Comment: Комментариями помечено

Comment: комментариями помечено утверждение. так в чем вопрос? чего вы хотите добиться? установить значение или понять почему так нельзя?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - ну понятно же - как присвоить значение obj2.y свойству этого же объекта d, мне тоже интересно!
   
    var obj={a:2};
    obj.b=3;
    var obj2={
    y:obj.b+obj.a,
    d:this.y // так тоже не канает :(
    };
    //obj2.d=obj2.y;//а вот так могу
    console.log(obj2.y);
    console.log(obj2.d);

Comment: а какая религиозная причина запрещает написать

     var obj2={y:obj.b+obj.a};
     obj2.d=obj2.y 

?

в дефайнере так как вы делаете нельзя

Comment: @Rules идиотский вопрос. как прострелить ногу такую же, которой еще нету?  
var obj2 = {y:obj.b+obj.a,d:obj.b+obj.a} какой в этом тайный смысл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в чем ошибка:

1)this указывает на контекст исполнения, т.е когда вы делаете

```
var obj2={
   d:this.y 
}
```

то, this указывает на объект window.

2) когда пишете так

```
var obj2={
   y: 'ололололо',
   d:y 
}
```

то в цепочке областей видимости(Scope chain) переменной "y" нет, однако, если вы сделаете так:

```
var y = '2'
var obj2={
   y: 'ололололо',
   d:y 
}
```

то получите свойство "d" со значением 2. Новое звено в цепочке видимости происходит при вступление в новый контекст исполнения...
Можете использовать конструктор, тогда this будет указывать на новоявленный объект:

```
function Foo(){
  this.x = 'lol',
  this.y = this.x
}
b = new Foo();
console.log(b.y)
```

Comment: @moron а предложенное автором вопроса то как реальзовать?

Comment: Rules, очевидно, что использовать конструктор или, как он уже сам знает, прямо указывая на объект d=obj2.y
 
Не обойти никак ограничения наложенные языком(ну я глупый - не знаю), я всего-лишь описал поведения, чтобы вопрошающий понимал процесс.

Comment: @mщron да мы все здесь это поняли и кстати `d=obj2.y` не проканает т.к obj2 undefined внутри объявления obj2 а вот как реализовать это и мне интересно (я не знаю как и не когда не задумывался) !

Comment: Понятно,через конструктор,спасибо,что обьяснили что к чему

Comment: @Undefined ответ @lampa лучше

Answer (score 3):

оно?

```
var obj = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 3
}

var obj2 = {
  y: obj.b + obj.a,
  get d() { return this.y; },
};

console.log(obj2.y);
console.log(obj2.d);
```

Comment: может кому нибудь понадобится вариация на тему http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XEzBc/

Answer (score 1):

Оно?

```
var obj={a:2};
obj.b=3;
var obj2={
y:obj.b+obj.a,
d:function(){return this.y}//не могу значению свойства d присвоить значению свойства y
};
console.log(obj2.d());
```

Comment: @koza4ok метод то да а как свойство?

Comment: Область видимости вроде только так позволит-This будет ссылатся на window.Замена свойства методом не критична в даном случае.